# The image of a compact set under a sequentially continuous real function is bounded

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $S$ be compact and let $f:S\longrightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be sequentially continuous. Then the image set $f(S)$ is bounded.

Comment: I would know how to show this for a sequentially compact $S$. Are you show that $S$ is compact, not sequentially compact?

Comment: According to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138161/non-trivial-convergent-sequence-in-stone-ech-compactification-of-mathbbn/138163#138163 the convergent sequences in the compact space $\beta\Bbb N$ are eventually constant, but then **every** function on $\beta\Bbb N$ is automatically sequentially continuous. But there is clearly in non-bounded function $\beta\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$

Comment: Oops! In my first comment I meant of course "are you sure", not "are you show" :-)

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yes, $S$ is only compact, not sequentially compact. Thank you for the suggestion about the space $\beta \mathbb{N}$. It seems to work well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for your comment. Sorry, but I could not understand your final comment about extending functions with compact codomain. So, do you think that $\beta \mathbb{N}$ does not provide a counterexample?

Comment: @jpar I retract the comment. Any function from $\beta\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that is unbounded will do, as this will be automatically sequentially continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The compact Hausdorff space $\beta\mathbb{N}$ has the property that all of its convergent sequences are eventually constant. See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/138161/2060) for an argument.

So any unbounded function $f$ from $\beta\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a counterexample.

Note that if $S$ were *sequentially* compact (which $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is not), then $f[S]$ would be sequentially compact in $\mathbb{R}$ (if $y_n = f(x_n)$ defines a sequence in $f[S]$, there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ converging to some $p \in S$. But then sequential continuity gives that $y_{n_k} = f(x_{n_k}) \rightarrow f(p)$, as $k \rightarrow \infty$.) and in a metric space sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness and so $f[S]$ would be (closed and) bounded.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider a sequence $x_n$ such as $|f(x_n)|\to \sup_S |f| $.

detail:

There is a subsequence $y_n$ convergent to a certain $y\in S$.
$$
 \sup_S |f| = \lim |f(x_n)| = \lim |f(y_n)| = |f(\lim y_n)| = |f(y)|<\infty$$

because $|f|$ is sequentially continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it seems that it uses sequential compactness of $S$, as it is possible to extract a converging subsequence. I assume only that $S$ is compact.